# codeigniter src relative path out sub-domain

Tags: codeigniter, path, href, src

This is my structure

```
public_html
 |-admin
 |-backend
     |-application
     |-...
 |-files
 |   |-user
 |      |-(id)
 |          |-logo.png
 |-system
 |-...
```

(尤川豪) I have 4 subdomains:

- admin.website.com -> admin folder (login)
- backend.website.com -> backend folder (login)
- usercount.website.com -> usercount folder (login)
- frontend.website.com -> frontend folder

All subdomains with codeigniter ans use the same system folder.

How can I put the src of the 'logo.png' in one backend view?

I appreciate any help on this question.

Comment: can you describe why your folder structure is like this?

Comment: why it's not 'application ' and 'system' folder right in the ROOT folder?